# Je me doute que tu sais faire ou je me doute que tu saches faire

Tags: subjonctif, indicatif

Le verbe **[se douter](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/se-douter/)** est supposé [être suivi de l'indicatif à l'affirmatif  et du subjonctif OU de l'indicatif à la forme négative](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwieg_7X7pz8AhU6VKQEHUqOCx8QFnoECAwQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lefigaro.fr%2Flangue-francaise%2Fexpressions-francaises%2Fje-me-doute-qu-il-est-ou-qu-il-soit-ne-faites-plus-la-faute-20190711%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3DL%27Acad%25C3%25A9mie%2520%25C3%25A9crit%2520ceci%253A%2520%25C2%25AB%2Cqu%27on%2520avait%2520des%2520preuves&usg=AOvVaw3SgiChCVG8wG7BbAW8gh-5).

Cependant, je trouve que la phrase "Je me doute que tu sais faire" (signifiant je m'attends à ce que tu saches faire ?) ne sonne pas français. Est-ce que je me trompe quelque part ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Je ne pense pas que tu en sois capable :

> Je doute que tu **saches** faire. ✅
> Je doute que tu **<s>sais</s>** faire. ❌

2. Je pense que tu en es capable :

> Je **me** doute que tu **sais** faire. ✅
> Je **me** doute que tu **<s>saches</s>** faire. ❌

Comment: Merci !! Y a-t-il une sorte d'explication logique ? Ou est-ce une règle que l'on doit juste connaître ?

Comment: Il faut surtout savoir que *douter* et *se douter* ont des sens quasiment opposés. Le subjonctif exprime le doute, l'hypothétique qui correspond à la première phrase alors que dans la deuxième, *tu sais faire* est considéré comme vrai.